# IllegalStateException while trying to install opensso on glassfishserver 3.1

Tags: glassfish, opensso, illegalstateexception

```
[#|2011-04-21T21:27:02.788+0530|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1|com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WSP1007: Policy exception occured when finishing WSDL parsing.
com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_0071_ERROR_MULTIPLE_ASSERTION_CREATORS_FOR_NAMESPACE(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing, com.sun.xml.ws.security.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator, com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.sourcemodel.PolicyModelTranslator.<init>(PolicyModelTranslator.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator.<init>(ModelTranslator.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator.<clinit>(ModelTranslator.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:962)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:191)
    at
```

Comment: I read that this error is because of conflict of Metro classes in both Server and web application. I am able to deploy the application successfully if I remove webservices-rt.jar from the opensso.jar.

Comment: But my SSO login URL throws too many redirects error when I try to access it from a browser

Answer (score 1):

just remove the dependency for webservice-rt.